# Intuition for S-parameter formulas?

Tags: rf, microwave, s-parameters

Wikipedia defines S-parameters as[1]:

$$
\boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{Sa}
$$

Where:

$$
a_i = \frac{1}{2}k_i (V_i + Z_i I_i)
$$

$$
b_i = \frac{1}{2}k_i (V_i - Z_i^* I_i)
$$

Saying it is defined in [2], which cites [3] for the definition. [3] As far as I can tell just defines it to be true.

What is the intuition for **why** it is useful for a and b take these values?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters

[2] Kurokawa, K., "Power Waves and the Scattering Matrix", IEEE Trans. Micr. Theory & Tech., Mar. 1965, pp. 194–202 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1125964

[3] Penfield, P., Jr., Noise in negative resistance amplifiers, IRE
Trans. on Circuit Theory, vol. CT-7, Jun 1960, pp 166-170. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1086655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus less on what **a** and **b** are defined to be in terms of the voltages and currents at those ports, and more on what they are intended to be.

They are travelling waves, **a** are waves incident on the ports, **b** are waves coming from the ports.

The voltage or current at the terminals of the port are made up of the superposition of the a and b waves. Voltages add, currents subtract, which is why you have the form in your question.

Why use waves?

When trying to describe networks, it helps to reduce all inputs bar one to zero, this simplifies the creation and interpretation of the formulae that we get. There are many ways to do this. One is with the popular h-matrix used to characterise transistors. However to set input voltages and input currents to zero requires that the test system create voltage sources, open circuits, short circuits etc. These are easy at DC, and possible at low frequency, but as the frequency rises into into the RF, it becomes increasingly difficult to realise them in a controlled, reproducible, accurate way.

What is much easier at RF is to work in a system of known impedance. We then throw travelling waves at the system, and measure what comes back. These are the **a** and **b** of Scattering Parameters. We can ensure that all ports bar one of a network have no travelling waves incident on them.

Comment: Your anwser clarifies the utility of waves and I can understand **a** and **b** superposing to create a resultant wave. I am still a bit unclear about where the ZI component comes from and why does **b** use the complex conjugate?

Comment: @EdwinShepherd a and b don't superpose to create a resultant wave, they are waves, they superpose to create a voltage and current at the terminals of the port. It would probably help you to write each wave as a complex phasor travelling in an impedance Z, add two contra-travelling waves, and work through the sums yourself. Intuitively, ZI is a voltage, we can only add terms of the same dimension together. Think of the complex conjugate as a result of the b wave travelling in the opposite direction to a.

Comment: @EdwinShepherd,  \$Z_i\$ is the characteristic impedance used as reference at each port. Very often they are all the same (often 50 ohms) and designated as \$Z_0\$. This term is the ratio between the voltage and current in a travelling wave on the transmission line. If you try to apply a signal with voltage and current that are different from \$Z_0\$ you can't get all the energy to flow in one direction, instead you get a superposition of waves travelling forward and backward (each of which has a V/I ratio of \$Z_0\$). You can start with the telegrapher's equations if you want to prove this.